# Java EE - java enterprise edition screencast?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, video

Is there any java enterprise screencast/video tutorial?

I found quite nice [test driven development](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9UVTwNs0GY) screencast and I am wondering if there is something like that (clear, english, easy, good quality) for Java EE?

I looked at youtube, iTunes and on google, but didn't find anything worth seeing.

I am looking for full featured playlist, channel, podcast or something... not single video, unless it is long and has a lot of details :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a video lecture on JSP and Servlets (Java EE Web tier) and also  Web Services (SOAP and WSDL) here:

http://cs259.tv/2007/fall/

The course is actually about XML, but it touches all kind of other related topics. I very much recommend it.